# Selenium Webdriver test's after deploy Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to run my Selenium Webdriver test's after I do a deployment to my staging environment.

But I run into this error.

```
"The stage refers to resources like queue 'Azure Pipelines', that have been protected with checks. Protected resources can only be used in YAML pipelines. For more details, refer to https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks."
```

The deploy agent is hosted on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some troubleshooting advices:

1. If you use a variable when setting the agent pool and agent in release pipeline, try replacing the variable with the specific value.
2. If you are using some resources or if your agent has set up Approval & Check, try to refresh the run page and manually pass the approval. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#troubleshooting-authorization-for-a-yaml-pipeline) for detailed information.